# MariaDB: MySQL Connector/Python update fails for some string lengths

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mariadb, mysql-connector-python, operationalerror

When updating a table entry, most strings work just fine but some don't. I assume it is related to the string length. For example, the strings "12345678" and "1234567890" work while the string "123456789" doesn't. Instead of correctly updating the entry, it throws a

**OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '...:3306', system error: 60 Operation timed out**

My script uses:

```
Python 3.7.6
mysql-connector-python     8.0.19
```

The db is running on the following system:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

Apache
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev
```

Code that does not work:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(...)
cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute('UPDATE table_1 SET name = "123456789"  WHERE id = 1;')
```

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    id int(9) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    ... name tinytext DEFAULT NULL, 
    ... PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_1`.  Is this `UPDATE` part of a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

To close this question:

"MySQL Connectors are only tested/support with MySQL Server." - Edwin Desouza

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?50,685171,685187#msg-685187